# Insert rows from one db/table into another db/table with distinctness around one column

Tags: sql-server

I have `db1.dbo.table` and `db2.dbo.table` which have the same schema.

`db1`'s table has more rows than `db2`'s table, and I'd like to add the missing rows to `db2`. If `db2` has a row matching the `id` of the row coming in from `db1` then I want to skip it. So the two tables look like this:

**db1.dbo.table**

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | a    |
| 2  | b    |
| 3  | c    |
-------------
```

**db2.dbo.table**

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | a    |
-------------
```

I would like to add rows `2` and `3` from `db1.dbo.table` to `db2.dbo.table`, but leave row `1` in-tact.

Pseudo-like code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```sql
with tb1 as (select id, name from db1.dbo.table)
insert into db2.dbo.table(name) where tb1.id > 1
```

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`. Tag the DBMS that you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insert into` with `not exists`:

```
insert into db2.dbo.table(id, name)
  select t.id, t.name
  from db1.dbo.table t
  where not exists (select 1 from db2.dbo.table t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```